# GooglePay DEVELOPER_ERROR "PaymentDataRequest.merchantId does not exist"

Tags: braintree, google-pay

After getting approval for a Google Pay `merchantId` I am getting the following error when trying to open the payment sheet.

```
{ statusCode: "DEVELOPER_ERROR", errorCode: 2, 
  statusMessage: "PaymentDataRequest.merchantId does not exist." }
```

I am using Braintree Payments, but that's not relevant to the end message.

```
   var paymentDataRequest = googlePaymentInstance.createPaymentDataRequest({

            merchantId: environment.payment.googlePayMerchantId,

            merchantInfo: {
                merchantId: environment.payment.googlePayMerchantId
            },

            transactionInfo: {
                currencyCode: 'USD',
                totalPriceStatus: 'ESTIMATED',
                totalPrice: this.priceEstimate.toFixed(2)
            },

            shippingAddressRequired: true,

            emailRequired: true,

            shippingAddressParameters: {
                allowedCountryCodes: data.countryCodes.map(c => c.code)
            }

            // cardRequirements: {
            //   // We recommend collecting billing address information, at minimum
            //   // billing postal code, and passing that billing postal code with all
            //   // Google Pay transactions as a best practice.
            //   billingAddressRequired: true
            // }
        });
```

Google is telling me everything looks OK their end.

Answer (score 4):

Turns out that passing an *extra* `merchantId` parameter in addition to `merchantInfo` can cause this.

So the fix was just this:

```
  // merchantId: environment.payment.googlePayMerchantId
```

However it also turns out that `merchantInfo` in `createPaymentDataRequest` is not needed if you've properly supplied `merchantId` when you first created the Braintree client in `braintree.googlePayment.create(...)`.

So the final fix in the above code is to remove both `merchantId` and `merchantInfo`.

I don't recall if this was just a mistake or an obsolete parameter from an older version of the API. In either case it's a very misleading error because the error says it's missing but it's actually an extra parameter.

Comment: You are the man! Thank you! This answer really helped me! Braintree documentation is totally wrong.